# iOS7 standalone simulator - how to use?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode7

There are couple of threads on running iOS7 simulator on Xcode 7 without any solution so I assume it's not possible to run unless one having Xcode 6.4 (my code can't compile on 6.4 so that's not an option).

So I am wondering is there any way to run iOS7 Simulator in standalone mode. I downloaded it from following link, installed but can't find it anywhere except some bom, plist files.  No SDK seems to have installed.

https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK7_1-7.1.1.1354140590.dmg

Any idea. I am using Yosemite.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 7.0 Simulator Runtime is not compatible with Yosemite.

The iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime is compatible with Yosemite, but not Xcode 7.

There is no need to mess with the manual download to install it yourself.  Installing the runtime with Xcode 6.4 will install it correctly for you in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles (which is where Xcode 7 looks as well).

If by "Standalone" you mean boot it with Simulator.app, you will not be able to do that trivially with the Simulator.app in Xcode 7 because of the adoption of library validation in Xcode 7's Simulator.  Some executables in the iOS 7.1 Simulator would need to be resigned to allow it to be used with Xcode 7's Simulator.  Even with that done (or taking steps to bypass security restrictions in OS X), the runtime will still not be compatible with Xcode 7.